# OpenCV - cv2.imRead() is returning None

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, webcam

Let me just start off by saying I've read multiple articles and other questions about this exact same error! Posting a question was my last resort. I'm working with Python 3.6.1 on 64-bit Windows 10.

I'm trying to do something relatively simple:

1. Snapshot from Webcam
2. Save it to the local Directory, read it from the local directory
3. Make a copy of it using the NP.copy() function

There's an error between number two and three.

```
if args["image"].upper() == "CAMERA": #If CLI Arg was 'camera'
    input("Hit any key to capture image...")
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()
    cv2.imwrite("SNAP.jpg", frame)    #save it
    image = cv2.imread("SNAP.jpg")    #load it
    print(image)                      #print as npArray
    cv2.imshow("SNAP", image)         #show it
    cv2.waitKey(0)
else:
    image = cv2.imread(args["image"])

orig = image.copy()
```

SNAP.jpg shows up in my local directory, and it also manages to `cv2.imshow()` just fine. However, when I `cv2.imread()` it, I get a None object back. More specifically, I get an empty numpy array:

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 ...

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  ...
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

Since it's empty, the `image.copy()` throws the NoneType error.

```
  File "text_detection.py", line 51, in <module>
    orig = image.copy()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
```

I've read  [Adrian's comprehensive guide to 'resolving'](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/26/opencv-resolving-nonetype-errors/) the NoneType error; no dice. I didn't try reinstalling OpenCV to address the possible image format libraries issue because another test of mine was able to `cv2.imread("myFile.png")` into `Tesseract` just fine.

I've also tried changing back and forth between `.jpg` and `.png` formats for the snapshot and tried supplying static/relative filepaths. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps `args["image"]` doesn't contain what you think it does (i.e. a valid filename)?

Comment: `image = cv2.imread("SNAP.jpg")` allows me to then `cv2.imshow(image)` - so I don't think it's having trouble finding the file.

Comment: Well, it's obviously taking the `else` branch, where you don't specify the filename explicitly, rather use the value from some dictionary -- `args["image"]`.

Comment: It isn't though, because it takes the picture and I see the webcam image pop up in real time in my file viewer. The `else` branch reads an existing file without taking a new one.

Comment: Make a proper [mcve] -- right now there are two different `imread`s and lack of context on which branch the algorithm takes and what all the variable values are. Also clarify things, because it's mighly confusing. You say that "imread returns None", but "imshow works" -- those don't go together, it can't return both `None` and a valid image array at the same time. Also "I get a None object back. More specifically, I get an empty numpy array" -- it can't be both, and what you show is definitely not an "empty array". All we can say is that it's some image with black corners (most is omitted).

Comment: Dan, I wouldn't ask the question if I weren't confused myself. I say "imread returns None" because that's what the traceback shows. I say "imshow works" because it does. Maybe it shouldn't, but it does. It wasn't clear enough in my question, so I'll clarify now: the second else branch does not run. As I commented previously, I can see the snapshot get taken. I understand a problem like this may be as confusing and frustrating for you as it is for me, but I do not appreciate your hostility. I have provided all of the information available to me. Please take my question at face-value.

Comment: Same for me, can't find any solution from now, `imread` is ok on Linux, return None on window. I think it is a bug, `plt` is a solution.